# Validation of dates in different fields in SharePoint

Tags: column, date-time, validation

My question is on validation of dates in SharePoint… 
If i have two date fields – start date(& time) and end date(&time). How do i validate these, so that a person cannot pick a time in between these? For example, if someone picks friday, 15th of June, 8-11am, another wont be able to pick friday 15th of June, 8-12pm or 8:30 – 10:00am or any time in between.

This involves comparing the current column with previously entered ones, how do i do this? I just got started on SharePoint.

Thanks in anticipation and kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't something which is easy using SharePoint.

The only way to validate using values from other list items is to use an EventReceiver. See [Creating SharePoint 2010 Event Receivers in Visual Studio 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg252010.aspx)

In the ItemAdding and ItemUpdating events you want to query for other items which collide with the selected datetimes.
To query for items you have to use [SPList.GetItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms457534.aspx) with a CAML query something like:

```
<Where>
  <And>
    <Gte>
      <FieldRef Name="EndDate" />
      <Value Type="DateTime>value of entered StartDate in ISO8601 format</Value>
    </Gte>
    <Lte>
      <FieldRef Name="StartDate" />
      <Value Type="DateTime>value of entered EndDate in ISO8601 format</Value>
    </Lte>
  </And>
</Where>
```

To format the dates you can use [SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.createiso8601datetimefromsystemdatetime.aspx)